# HTML links that exit UIWebView

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, safari

I have my application iPhone Validated by Apple.
I have a UIWebView and I want to exit this UIWebView to go to Safari using HTML links but it's not working.

Please i Need Help

Comment: i tried html tag like href redirect http

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

Add this to the UIWebView delegate:

```
 -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
        if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i can't change the application it's already validated by apple

Comment: k try with one example and let me know your requirement is solved by this one or not?

Comment: This is the only solution, you can't do anything server side to break out of a web view, you'd have to update the binary.